# How to merge pandas dataframe and filter duplicate content in different column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently learning pandas in python 2.7. I'm learning merge() method in pandas.

Here is my code to create dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

eibi = {'A': ['aaa','bbb','ccc','eee','fff'],
        'B': ['bbb','aaa','ccc','fff','eee']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(eibi)

print df
```

and the ouput is:

```
     A    B  
0  aaa  bbb
1  bbb  aaa
2  ccc  ddd
3  eee  fff
4  fff  eee
```

I want to merge the dataframe by the row in the dataframe itself. The goal is if the cell in column B match with the cell in column A, move that cell to column C and D.

I hope the dataframe below will make it clear about my expected dataframe.

```
     A    B    C    D
0  aaa  bbb  bbb  aaa
2  ccc  ddd  
3  eee  fff  fff  eee
```

I was trying to duplicate df dataframe then merge it using merge() method and using left merge. Here is my code:

```
fd = df

new_dataframe = pd.merge(left=df, right=fd, left_on='A', right_on='B', how='left')

print new_dataframe
```

and the output is:

```
   A_x  B_x  A_y  B_y
0  aaa  bbb  bbb  aaa
1  bbb  aaa  aaa  bbb
2  ccc  ddd  
3  eee  fff  fff  eee
4  fff  eee  eee  fff
```

My question is "How to remove index 1 and 4?" and "Is there the other way to get the expected result?"

Comment: @Tai thanks for your attention. Are my question not clearly enough?

Comment: No... not clear enough to me.   """The goal is if the cell in column B match with the cell in column A, move that cell to column C and D.""" Move cell B to both column C and D? Please clarify.

Comment: @Tai I was include expected dataframe. My question has been answered. By the way thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure that I have seen your expected output. Just text description does not match your expected output. Never mind. Your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is how to remove index 1 and 4

```
output[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(output.values)).duplicated()]
Out[816]: 
   A_x  B_x  A_y  B_y
0  aaa  bbb  bbb  aaa
2  ccc  ddd          
3  eee  fff  fff  eee
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Then i will learn hard to undersand how it's works.